# How could I build a Inner-Net of multiple networks?

Tags: network, internet

I have multiple theoretical(not at the time being) WiFi Networks with one on each property(3 properties) and I want to have the three networks connected similarly to the internet. For example, I would have one hosting server and three networks that would be completely isolated from the internet but would be connected to each other through the server. Is this in any way possible or would it have to run using the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: FOR USING LAN NETWORK]

[image: FOR USING INTERNET AS A SECURE VPN PROFILE]
THERE ARE TWO OPTIONS AVAILABLE :

Comment: Thank you so much. I had assumed I planned to run Optic between the properties and plan to use method one. If I used option one would each of the properties have there own public IP addresses if viewed from the hosting server or if trying to connect to a property from a different property? I'm really hoping I can keep the networks separate because they are residential properties with lots of infrastructure at each property.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are three options:

1. You deploy your own cabling to connect the locations.
2. You rent dedicated cabling from someone else.
3. You use VPN tunnels to connect over the general Internet. You can deny Internet acess from your networks, so only the tunnel gateways come in contact with it.

If line-of-sight exists you can also use wireless methods.